# Diagonal sparse matrix obtained from a sparse coo_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I built some sparse matrix `M` in Python using the `coo_matrix` format. I would like to find an efficient way to compute:

```
A = M + M.T - D
```

where `D` is the restriction of `M` to its diagonal (`M` is potentially very large). I can't find a way to efficiently build `D` while keeping a `coo_matrix` format. Any ideas?

Could `D = scipy.sparse.spdiags(coo_matrix.diagonal(M),0,M.shape[0],M.shape[0])` be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a faster `coo`  diagonal:

```
msk = M.row==M.col
D1 = sparse.coo_matrix((M.data[msk],(M.row[msk],M.col[msk])),shape=M.shape)
```

`sparse.tril` uses this method with `mask = A.row + k >= A.col`  (`sparse/extract.py`)

Some times for a (100,100) `M` (and `M1 = M.tocsr()`)

```
In [303]: timeit msk=M.row==M.col; D1=sparse.coo_matrix((M.data[msk],(M.row[msk],M.col[msk])),shape=M.shape)
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop

In [305]: timeit D=sparse.diags(M.diagonal(),0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 358 µs per loop
```

So the `coo` way of getting the diagional is fast, at least for this small, and very sparse matrix (only 1 time in the diagonal)

If I start with the `csr` form, the `diags` is faster.  That's because `.diagonal` works in the `csr` format:

```
In [306]: timeit D=sparse.diags(M1.diagonal(),0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 176 µs per loop
```

But creating `D` is a small part of the overall calculation.  Again, working with `M1` is faster.   The sum is done in `csr` format.

```
In [307]: timeit M+M.T-D
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop

In [308]: timeit M1+M1.T-D
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 ms per loop
```

---

Another way to do the whole thing is to take advantage of that fact that `coo` allows duplicate `i,j` values, which will be summed when converted to `csr` format.  So you could stack the `row, col, data` arrays for `M` with those for `M.T` (see `M.transpose` for how those are constructed), along with masked values for `D`.  (or the masked diagonals could be removed from `M` or `M.T`)

For example:

```
def MplusMT(M):
    msk=M.row!=M.col;
    data=np.concatenate([M.data, M.data[msk]])
    rows=np.concatenate([M.row, M.col[msk]])
    cols=np.concatenate([M.col, M.row[msk]])
    MM=sparse.coo_matrix((data, (rows, cols)), shape=M.shape)
    return MM

# alt version with a more explicit D
#    msk=M.row==M.col;
#    data=np.concatenate([M.data, M.data,-M.data[msk]])
```

`MplusMT` as written is very fast because it is just doing array concatenation, not summation.  To do that we have to convert it to a `csr` matrix.

```
MplusMT(M).tocsr()
```

which takes considerably longer.  Still this approach is, in my limited testing, more than 2x faster than `M+M.T-D`.  So it's a potential tool for constructing complex sparse matrices.

Comment: Great ! Thanks for your detailed and precised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
D = diags(M.diagonal(), 0, format='coo')
```

This will still build an M-size 1d array as an intermediate step, but that will probably not be so bad.

Comment: I'd leave `D` in its default `dia` format, and let `sparse` transform it during the addition.  `M+M.T` is `csr`, the best format for math.